# Vim: find lines with less occurrences of string

Tags: vim

In a data file I need to find all lines that contain less than 10 times the pattern |^|
I need them in two ways:

1. a search, so I can go through the file and examine the data
2. as a list to be copied, including the next line

I use Gvim in Windows.

So far I've tried along the lines of:

```
/[|^|]{,9}
/[|^|]*{,9}
:g/\v(\|[^|^|]*){,9}/p
```

Is anyone able to help me?

Edit: an example (as real data is not allowed to be used)

```
abc|^|def|^|ghi|^|jkl|^|mno|^|pqr|^|stu|^|vwx|^|yza|^|bcd|^|efg
abc|^|def|^|ghi|^|jkl|^|mno|^|pqr|^|stu|^|vwx|^|yza|^|
bcd|^|efg
abc|^|def|^|ghi|^|jkl|^|mno|^|pqr|^|stu|^|vwx|^|yza|^|bcd|^|efg
```

Final solution:

```
:v/\v(\|\^\|.*){10}
```

Comment: Can we have a proper sample?

Comment: Thank you for asking @romainl. I've added an example with dummy data, as the real data is prohibited from sharing

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this one. I think it will help.

`/\(|^|.*\)\{10}`

or with \v

`/\v(\|\^\|.*){10}`

Comment: Hi @Gopito, I've tried your suggestion, but it does not seem to highlight the correct lines as the message returned is: E486: Pattern not found

Comment: I've corrected my answer with another search pattern variant.
Also I have vim version 8.2.2050.

Comment: Your example was a perfect basis to complete the task: :v/\v(\|\^\|.*){10}

Edit: my internet page was not refreshed and only noticed your change after putting in this comment. I will mark your edited suggestion as the answer. Thank you so much!